# reverse hex 0x in javascript

Tags: javascript, hex

I am playing with code code to make sprites. I have a right facing sprite and have been manually creating a left facing sprite. I am looking for a way to reverse a hex 0x to make the sprite face left.  one line of the sprite is 0x01555500 and the reverse of that is 0x05555400. Does anyone know how I can do this using JavaScript?

**Example:**

the array:

```
[
    0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000,
    0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000,
    0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000,
    0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000,
    0x00554000, 0x01555500, 0x02AFB000, 0x0BBFBF00,
    0x0BAFEFC0, 0x0AFFAA00, 0x00FFFC00, 0x029A8000,
    0x0A9A6A00, 0x2A956A80, 0x3E75DBC0, 0x3F555FC0,
    0x3D5557C0, 0x01505400, 0x0A802A00, 0x2A802A80
]
```

and the reverse would be:

```
[
    0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000,
    0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000,
    0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000,
    0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000,
    0x00155000, 0x05555400, 0x00EFA800, 0x0FEFEE00,
    0x3FBFAE00, 0x0AAFFA00, 0x03FFF000, 0x002A6800,
    0x0A9A6A00, 0x2A956A80, 0x3E75DBC0, 0x3F555FC0,
    0x3D5557C0, 0x01505400, 0x0A802A00, 0x2A802A80
]
```

Comment: What is the logic of reversing?

Comment: I have an array of these hex values, and they create a sprite that faces right, if I can use code to reverse them, I will not have to manually reverse them, I can just tell my program to do it.

Comment: I can't guess how your sprite data is represented, or how `0x01555500` is reversed to `0x05555400`, If this is suposed to represent an array of horizontal pixels, how much bits each pixel has?

Comment: new Sprite([
        0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000,
        0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000,
        0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000,
        0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000,
        0x00554000, 0x01555500, 0x02AFB000, 0x0BBFBF00,
        0x0BAFEFC0, 0x0AFFAA00, 0x00FFFC00, 0x029A8000,
        0x0A9A6A00, 0x2A956A80, 0x3E75DBC0, 0x3F555FC0,
        0x3D5557C0, 0x01505400, 0x0A802A00, 0x2A802A80])

Comment: You still didn't tell us the logic of the reversing. How to do you know the reverse of a hex code? What is the algorithm?

Comment: the reverse of which is :
new Sprite([
        0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000,
        0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000,
        0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000,
        0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000,
        0x00155000, 0x05555400, 0x00EFA800, 0x0FEFEE00,
        0x3FBFAE00, 0x0AAFFA00, 0x03FFF000, 0x002A6800,
        0x0A9A6A00, 0x2A956A80, 0x3E75DBC0, 0x3F555FC0,
        0x3D5557C0, 0x01505400, 0x0A802A00, 0x2A802A80])

Comment: oh... it breaks it down into the binary, F = 1111, and 0 = 0000.

Answer (score 2):

You could use this:

```
function reverse(line) {
    line2 = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 31; i++) {
        line2 = (line2 << 1) | (line & 1)
        line >>= 1;
    }
    return line2;
}
```

```js
function reverse(line) {
    line2 = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 31; i++) {
        line2 = (line2 << 1) | (line & 1)
        line >>= 1;
    }
    return line2;
}
// demo:
var line = 0x01555500;
var line2 = reverse(line);
console.log(('0000000' + line.toString(16)).slice(-8));
console.log(('0000000' + line2.toString(16)).slice(-8));
```

Comment: Thank you, I would first need to parse out the 0x, and add it again to the beginning. any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean *parse out the 0x*? `0x` is just a notation that allows you to express numbers in hexadecimal format, but it is just notation. The function I provide works on numbers, not strings. Whether you note 0xF or 15, it is both the same number. There is no real "0x" stored. I added a snippet you can run to see a string representation of the input/output.

Comment: oh, thank you again. This is the first time I've ever worked with hex in code, I will give it a try and let you know the outcome.